# (Smooth) Isoline Extraction from TIN - Algorithms

Tags: tin, nearest-neighbor

Can anyone point me to a clear document or algorithm for extracting smooth isolines from a Triangular Irregular Network?  I've seen some examples using the jagged linear methods, but can't seem to find good documentation on how to do the process using a smoother method like Natural Neighbor / Radial Basis / Quadric / etc...

Thanks!

Comment: May be duplicated
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8985/java-contour-algorithm/185782#185782

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Digital elevation models and TIN algorithms (M. van Kreveld)](http://people.cs.uu.nl/marc/papers/terrainsurvey.pdf), section 1.6 may help.

Answer (score 0):

May be [duplicated](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8985/java-contour-algorithm/185782#185782). [This](https://bitbucket.org/temnur/isoline/wiki/Home) is open java source for Delaunay Triangulation and interpolation